# Get product position from specific category in attribut.phtml

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 we used this code, to get and display the position number in attributes.phtml. How can I change it for Magento 2?

```
$yourCatIds = array(111);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();
if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    echo $this->__('Position: ');}
```

```
$yourCatIds = array(111);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();
// Returns all product ids with its position
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($yourCatIds);
$productPositions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);
$CatIds = array(2);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();
    if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    echo $productPositions[$_product->getId()];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the position of category by category Id using Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory as follows:

...

protected $_categoryFactory;

...

public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory

) {

```
$this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
```

}

public function execute() {

```
$yourCatIds = array(111);
foreach ($yourCatIds as $catId)
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
    $productPositions  = $category->getProductsPosition();
    $catProductPositions[$catId] = $productPositions;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php` resource model's `getProductsPosition()` method. It does just that:

```php
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProductsPosition($category)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
            $this->getCategoryProductTable(),
            ['product_id', 'position']
        )->where(
            "{$this->getTable('catalog_category_product')}.category_id = ?",
            $category->getId()
        );
        $websiteId = $category->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        if ($websiteId) {
            $select->join(
                ['product_website' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_website')],
                "product_website.product_id = {$this->getTable('catalog_category_product')}.product_id",
                []
            )->where(
                'product_website.website_id = ?',
                $websiteId
            );
        }
        $bind = ['category_id' => (int)$category->getId()];

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchPairs($select, $bind);
    }
```